# 2 Select Statements, 1 Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working on a project which requires 2 different tables assigning a number to a common variable. I can get 0 and 1 to work, but value 2 will not work. What am I missing?

```
declare @rtval int
, @primarykey nvarchar(25)

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN

set @primarykey = ( select top 1 2
                from dbo.firsttable ftv
                where ftv.field = @ftvID
                and ftv.Target like 'CASE1'
                )

set @primarykey = ( select top 1 1
                from dbo.secondtable fv
                join dbo.external ext on fv.external1 = ext.xID
                where fv.yID = @yID
                and fv.Target1 like 'CASE2'
                )

if ISNUMERIC(@primarykey) = 1
begin set @rtval = convert (int, @primarykey)
end

else

begin set @rtval = 0
end
```

I can get 0 and 1 to work, but never 2. Is there something I missing?

Comment: You are setting the variable to "2" and then setting it to either "1" or "0"

Comment: Also why `if ISNUMERIC(@primarykey)`? This is confusing.

Comment: Oh, and your second query overwrites the value of the first making it pointless.

Comment: You set the variable then overwrite it with the second set. It looks like you need 2 variables, compare them then use the result you want? I'm also a bit confused on the intent.

Comment: WTH is top 1 2? That is horrific and incredibly confusing. But to top it off you are forcing it into an nvarchar(25). You should look at using EXISTS instead of that very strange syntax you have going on there. And why check for ISNUMERIC? Wouldn't checking for NULL make more sense?

Comment: Pretend for a moment that we don't have access to your database - neither your table definitions, nor the data they contain. We don't know what *input* you're providing here, nor how several variables or parameters that are *used* above but not defined are given values, nor a *clear* idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Trying to set the variable to 0 (default, neither situations), 1 (situation 1) or 2 (situation 2). I've changed the course changing both to separate variables in order to help streamline input.

The Code was written by someone else, I am attempting to clean it up without all much training in SQL. I've set both to INT (integers) to make things easier.

The Select Top 1 2 I'm a little puzzled with myself but it was a part of the original code, I suspect the second level in the Select Statement can be a big part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how 2 would ever be returned by this code.  I think you want something like this...

```
DECLARE @rtval INT =  CASE
        WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT  *
            FROM    dbo.firsttable ftv
            WHERE   ftv.field = @FTVID
            AND     ftv.target LIKE 'CASE1'
            ) THEN 2
        WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT  *
            FROM    dbo.secondtable fv
            JOIN    dbo.external ext on fv.external1 = ext.xID
            WHERE   fv.yID = @yID
            AND     fv.Target1 LIKE 'CASE2'
            ) THEN 1
        ELSE
            0
    END ;
```

If you are using an older version of SQL Server, you may need to declare @rtval separately from a SET or SELECT to populate it.

I am assuming that you want to check for CASE1 before you check for CASE2.  If not, just reverse the order of then WHEN clauses.

Also, doing a LIKE without any wildcards is a straight equality check, so it would probably be more efficient to replace the LIKE with an =.

Comment: For some strange reason I managed to get it to work. But the solution above is less confusing and close to what where I was going as well. Thanks.

Comment: I'd love it if you could upvote the or mark as solution if you think it's worth it so I get a little rep from it.